# Ошибка при запуске приложения с MapActivity  [Закрыт]

Tags: android, google-maps-api, java

Подскажите что и как исправить если выдаёт ошибку: `INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY`,
а в LogCat:

> `Package requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.maps failing`

Столько информации перерыла, ничего вразумительного. Помогите, плиз!

Comment: Забыла ещё одну строчку про флажок : open your project properties, un-select the "Is Library" checkbox, and click Apply to make your project a normal Android project (not a library project).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здравствуйте. 
Попробуйте сделать все эти действия:

- Правый клик по проекту `-> Android tools -> Fix Project Properties`. В верху, в Эклип выбираем пункт меню `Project->Clean`, ставим галочку на `Clean projects selected below`, выбираем свой проект и нажимаем "Ок".
- Проверьте ещё раз или проект создан для `Google APIs`, правой кнопкой по проекту `->Properties->Android`. Можете попробовать выбрать  `Google APIs` для другой версии `Android`. Так же проверьте эмулятор, правильно ли он создан!
- Ну и последнее что я могу посоветовать, это проверьте свои ключи которые вы получали для работы с `Google Maps`, может вы их где то не правильно ввели или не правильно получили.

П.С. ссылки для работы с Google Maps: [link1](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview), [link2](http://habrahabr.ru/post/131252/) - в конце поста есть много полезных ссылок на рус. статьи, [link3](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/android-google-maps-tutorial.html), [link4](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android)

Comment: Спасибо за понимание и оперативность! Проверила проект - всё норм, на Google APIs minSDK 8, эмулятор тоже соответствует этой версии - но всё равно ошибочка, проект даже не запускается ((. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как ключи проверять.

Comment: Ещё про версию проекта хочу уточнить: minSDK 8, target 15. А эмулятор должен соответствовать минимальной версии, то есть 8, правильно ли я поняла этот момент?

Comment: Да вы правильно поняли, а иначе у вас была бы ошибка что версия андроида на эмуляторе не соответствует минимальной версии андроида в проекте. Я добавил в ответ несколько ссылок на статьи, где описаны примеры работы с Google Maps.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, буду проверять.

Comment: tigr240172, отдельное спасибо!!! ))

Answer (score 1):

Решила проблему! Дело было вот в чём:

> Next, set the project's Properties to indicate that it is a library project:
>
> In the Package Explorer, right-click the library project and select Properties. In the Properties window, select the "Android" properties group at left and locate the Library properties at right.
> Select the "is Library" checkbox and click Apply.
> Click OK to close the Properties window.

Может кому пригодится и этот нюанс.

Answer (score 0):

Ужс, первая ссылка по запросу твоей ошибки в гугле: [Shared library missing in android.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283398/shared-library-missing-in-android)

В 2х словах, на эмуляторе нету либы для карт, что бы была, надо создать эмулятор по инструкции по ссылке выше.

Comment: Хмм! У меня приложение создано на базе Google API так же как и эмулятор. Хотя по сути если используешь SDK, то карты включены в него изначально, насколько я понимаю. Сейчас создала новый эмулятор (по инструкции) так он вообще мне пишет "Android library projects cannot be launched".

Comment: Вообще я в Android-е новичок, так что не пинайте сильно, пожалуйста...